# Rails Save File Checkbox

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, checkbox, nested-attributes

How can I make it so that my info only gets stored if the checkbox is checked. Here is what I have so far:

```
<% @extra.each do |extra| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :purchaseds do |builder| %>
    <div class="label-field">
      <%= builder.label :name, extra.name %>
      <p><%= extra.description %></p>
    </div>
    <div class="text-field">
      $<%= extra.price %>
      <%= builder.check_box :purchased %>
    </div>

    #I WOULD LIKE THIS TO ONLY GET SAVED IF THE CHECK BOX FOR PURCHASED IS CHECKED
    <%= builder.hidden_field :name, :value => extra.name %>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :description, :value => extra.description %>
    <%= builder.hidden_field :price, :value => extra.price %>  
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

My client asked to be able to add extra services himself, and then users could be able to choose if they want to purchase them as accessories to their order. So what I did was I made a table called Extra (for extra services) and another table called Purchased. Purchased belongs to Order and is a nested attribute.

Comment: The title of your post is "Rails Save File Checkbox" but I don't see anything in your code about files. Are there files involved?

Answer (score 1):

In your purchaseds model add validations:

```
  validates_presence_of :name, :description, :price, :if => :purchased
```

**Update**

Add `:reject_if` option to your purchaseds parent model in

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :purchaseds, :reject_if => {|attrs| !attrs[:purchased]}
```